# How to use the Plots pane in Spyder 4

Tags: spyder

I want to use the Plots Pane to look at earlier plots, but nothing ever shows up. I tried changing the graphics backend, but that didn't do anything. I can't find any documentation on the plots pane either.

Current Version:
Python 3.7.6 64-bit | Qt 5.12.5 | PyQt5 5.12.3 | Windows 10

Answer (score 10, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) You need to be sure that the Inline backend is selected in our Preferences:

[image: Inline backend selected]

Then create some plots on any IPython console:

[image: Plots in the IPython console]

and you'll see the history of plots in our Plots pane:

[image: Plots pane]

- Verify the plot plane is visible with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>g</kbd> or <kbd>View</kbd> + <kbd>Panes</kbd> + <kbd>Plots</kbd>
- A reboot may be necessary if changes are made.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

As you can see plot can be seen inline as well as plot option.